# Access parent's members when extending android.widget.xxx

Tags: java, android

I'm writing a custom gridview this way:

```
public class MyGridView extends GridView {
....
    public void myMethod() {
        if (mDataChanged) { // cannot access this member declared in it's parent class AdapterView
        }
    }
｝
```

I know I can access access package-private members through reflection, but I'm looking for a better way.

I tried to change package name to `android.widget`, still no luck.

Is there a way I can access that package-private member other than reflection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best policy would be not to touch things declared private because these things may change with the next release of Android.

You also have an option to copy a portion of Android source, but that usually means copying a whole lot of code.

Comment: thanks, seems like copying a whole lot of code is inevitable